# django gmail smtp timeout on GAE environment but run ok on local... sending 1 line of text

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-app-engine

python3.11 django4.2

on settings.py :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'the email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'the password'
```

send email function :

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage(
  "subject", 
  "message", 
  settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER , 
  ["the destination"]
)
email.contentsubtype = "html"
email.send()
```

error log on gae result in timeout
*5 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 169.254.1.1, server: , request: "GET /ajax/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/ajax/", host: "test.de.r.appspot.com"

requests.post to outside web also result in the same timeout error ex:

```
def urltest(request):
    import requests
    url = "https://enmzxk3tnwgrr.x.pipedream.net/" #requestbin url
    response = requests.post(url, data={'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'})
    response.raise_for_status()
    return HttpResponse(response.text)
```

i have tried setting nginx timeout to be 600 sec... hence now my code tried to run the code for 10 minutes and timeout